Cancelling unintentional movement of an object when dragging it in a QGIS layout
Very often when working with a layout in QGIS I select the wrong object because it is higher in the items list. Right at the moment of dragging this object I realize that I have selected the wrong object.
I know that I can undo the action in the QGIS layout using ctr + z, but I'm not satisfied with that.
Is it possible to undo this action right at the moment of dragging an object? (Pressing the Esc does not help).


You could lock all items you don't want to move, so the mistake doesn't happen in the first place. Other than that I have no idea.

ctrl-z will undo the last move (there is also a back arrow I think)
